Discount Contribution extension not working on WordPress
I'm testing version 1.1 with CiviDiscount 3.8.8 and CiviCRM 5.69.5.
The discount field is rendered in the Contribution form but nothing happens when I enter the code and click Apply. The page is reloaded without the query strings ?reset=1&id=91.
After filling out the entire form and clicking Review Your Contribution, I receive error:

The discount code you entered is invalid.

